# PHP Reading txt file and store data in hashtable

Tags: php, file-io, hashtable

I have several .txt files of this format:

```
ProductID|Platform|TitleID|Cat|Barcode|..

TitleID|TitleArticle|TitleName|..

ProductID|ImgID|Img|ImgType|..

ProductID|AnnotationID|AnnotationType|AnnotationText|..

ProductGenreID|ProductID|Genre1|...
```

This goes on for about 22000 lines each. I want to read these files and store their data in db. But as you can seen the files are interrelated on the bases of ProductID and TitleID, so when I loop through the parent product file and then pass the PID to the child file to find the corresponding record it will loop again 22000 times for each file which is too time consuming and will take days to complete.

Anyhow, my thought is to use a PHP hashtable to store these file, and then search for the records - I guess this approach will reduce the complexity of my current script(Do you think this is the best path to follow?If not,what do you suggest?)

If yes, I'm not sure how to achieve this in PHP.

@Ahmed and @Oswald The problem is I don't have same Db schema as the file suggest, here I'm pasting some code as well for better understanding..

```
public function getGames()
{
    $resource = self::DATAFILES.'data sample\Product.txt';

    $games = array_slice($this->readFile($resource), 1); 
    $data = array();
    $count = 1;
    foreach($games as $records)
    {
        $game = new Games();
        $attributes = explode($this->delimiter,$records);
        $game->api   =  (int) $attributes[0];
        echo $game->title = (string) $this->getTitle($attributes[2]);
        $game->titleID = (string) $attributes[2];
        $game->desc = (string) $this->getDescription($attributes[0]);
        $game->console = (string) $attributes[1];
        $game->genre = (string) implode(',', $this->getProductGenre($attributes[0]));
        $game->screenshot = (string) $this->getScreenshot($attributes[0]);
        $game->publisher =  (string) $this->getCompany($this->getPublisher($attributes[0]));
        $game->developers =  (string) $this->getCompany($this->getDeveloper($attributes[0]));
        $game->barcode = (string) $attributes[4];
        $game->image = $this->getCoverImage($attributes[0]);
        $game->releaseDate = strtotime($attributes[8]);
        $data[] = $game;
        //if($count == 1000): break; else: $count++; endif;
    }
        return $data;

}
public function getTitle($titleID)
{
    $resource = self::DATAFILES.'data sample\Title.txt';

    $titles = array_slice($this->readFile($resource), 1); 

    foreach($titles as $records)
    {
        $attributes = explode($this->delimiter,$records);

        $pattern = '/^' . preg_quote($attributes[0], '/') . '$/';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $titleID))
        {
            return $attributes[2];
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

so the return $data actually got the fields which I need for my db games table here check the schema

CREATE TABLE `games` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `api` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` tinytext CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `titleID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `console_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `genre_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `developers` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `barcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `screenshot` varchar(999) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `release_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3075 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a process using several steps?

1. Grab each line and interpret the type of data
2. Store the line in a table using the ID and resulting type in a table
3. Run different queries for each item and reference the DB data now so you can make the links
4. Parse the data and insert into table again

I guess what I'm getting at is get the data into the database so you can reference it on a very basic level. Then parse and relate data. This way you can jump around the data in a non-linear way rather than huge loop through text.

Comment: Please find my reply in the question above! as comment field won't allow much of a content

Answer (score 0):

1. loop through the parent product file and store its data in the database.
2. loop through the child file and store its data in the database.
3. loop through any other file and store their data in the database.

There is no need to insert the related child records immediately after its parent record is inserted.

Comment: Please find my reply in the question above! as comment field won't allow much of a content